# RHEL7 Tomcat setenv.sh

Tags: tomcat, rhel, setenv

I wanted to use setenv.sh in RHEL7 tomcat7 standard installation. However, the file is not used. I created it in /usr/share/tomcat/bin. 
But as there are no more script files in this directory, I suppose its probably not the right place. What works is to set my values directly in /usr/sbin/tomcat file, but this file might be overwritten by a future update.

Comment: the script setenv.sh is no longer found in the standard tomcat7 zip archives but it can be created and used. I have downloaded the last tomcat7 release ZIP archive and it contains the usual scripts in the bin/ subdirectory excepting setenv.sh. The catalina.sh looks for setenv.sh -- if setenv.sh can be read, then it is run. Please read  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/RUNNING.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Eran Medan answered on https://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04, setenv.sh is not used under RHEL because the 
/usr/sbin/tomcat6 script is NOT calling catalina.sh but simply calls the tomcat bootstrap class directly.

The best place is to put the values under /etc/tomcat6/tomcat6.conf 
As you mentioned, modifying /usr/sbin/tomcat is not the right way to do it.

@Jdamian : You're right if you use a zip archive but Josef Vogt is using the tomcat package on red hat repository.